# Space and time complexity of balanced parentheses enumeration algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, recursion, space-complexity, permutations

Consider the following recursive algorithm for printing all balanced strings with $n$ left and right parentheses. It is called with *prefix* = $\epsilon$ (the empty string):

A(*prefix*):

1. If *prefix* contains $n$ right parens: print *prefix* and return.
2. If *prefix* contains more left parens than right parens: call A(*prefix* + ")").
3. If *prefix* contains less than $n$ left parens: call A(*prefix* + "(").

As an optimization, instead of counting the number of left and right parens at each step of the recursion, we carry them around (so A gets two more parameters, which are the number of parens of teach type in *prefix*).

For example, when $n = 3$, this outputs the following strings:

```
   ()()()
   ()(())
   (())()
   (()())
   ((()))
```

Comment: I understand that; it is just that it would be helpful if you provided details of the problem statement. For example, if you had provided the example you have edited in earlier, I probably wouldn't have misunderstood your code in my previous comment.

Comment: On this site, we describe algorithms as pseudocode. Not everybody can read Java, and besides the pseudocode will be dramatically shorter.

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see a question here, just a series of statements.  This is a question-and-answer site, so it is important to be explicit about what question you want an answer to.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple enumeration algorithm. The space complexity is $O(n)$, and the time complexity is the size of the output, since you do not doing anything useless.

By the way, the number of rows in the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). $C_n=\frac 1 {n+1}\binom {2n} n$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby We don't count space on the output tape.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I wasn't counting space on the output tape; I was counting space used on the work-tape to manage the recursion. (Except I miscounted it so I've deleted my comment.) Nonetheless, I think it would be helpful if the answer justified the $O(n)$ claim, if only for the benefit of those of us who've not yet had enough coffee.

Comment: I see you deleted you code. The recursive function will run at most $2n$ nested levels to print a line. The memory of each function call is $O(1)$. Therefore, you're using an $O(n)$ space.

Comment: The time complexity is the Catalan number so? I have seen people wrongly saying that is an exponential algorithm but I was not sure about that... and for this reason, I posted the question over here. @Mohemnist thanks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number
This is the source http://geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-balanced-parentheses/

Comment: "the time complexity is the size of the output, since you do not doing anything useless." In cases like this where the size of the output is larger than the input, it is common to consider the average time per output (i.e. total time over number of outputs) or the worst-case of the following three subcases: (1) time from starting to returning the first output, (2) time from returning one output to returning the next output, and (3) time from returning the last output to the computation terminating.